# Alert message before rendering to a new webpage in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am a beginner in NODEJS. I am trying to show an alert message on the browser before rendering to a new page. I was unable to do so. Can you please guide me ?

### hbs file

```
<form id="form1" action="/emp_details" method="post">
    <label for="NAME_FIELD">NAME</label>
    <input id="NAME_FIELD" type="text" name="NAME_FIELD" autocomplete="off">
    <br><br>

    <label for="EMAIL_FIELD">EMAIL</label>
    <input id="EMAIL_FIELD" type="text" name="EMAIL_FIELD" autocomplete="off">
    <br><br>

    <label for="GENDER">GENDER</label>
    <select
    id="GENDER" name="GENDER">
    <option value="male">MALE</option>
    <option value="female">FEMALE</option>
    <option value="others">OTHERS</option>

    </select><br><input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

### js file

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
})

app.post('/emp_details', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    //SOMETHING HERE TO ALERT
    res.render('/emp_details')
});
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to halt execution to show an alert on the server side? or did you mean you want to show an alert on the client side? Node runs on the server HTML/JavaScript run on the client.

Comment: I want to display an alert on the browser.

Comment: Then you need at add the script to your view, /emp_details, and just put the alert as the first script in the header. The page will still start to render but halt execution before completing until the user dismisses the alert.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you please show an example of how to use jquery in this case. Thank you.

Comment: No need for jQuery, `alert('this is my super awesome custom alert message!');`

Comment: Thank you. But how does the browser know if the data was processed at the server..?

Comment: Because it was sent a response. Think of the browser as a dumb client, it has no idea what happened on the server or if what actualy happened was what was supposed to happen. All the browser cares about is if it got a response and rendering the content of that response. If the server didn't do what it was supposed to do you need to either update the model/view to display that to the user or redirect to another page.